# Why is my client server udp code not sending?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, udp, ip-address

I have been interested in tcp, udp and named pipes lately and am trying to teach myself. I am trying to get a udp connection set up to see how it works. I have a client and server program in windows form app with a richtextBox1 and btStart. I would like to get this setup on the same computer and then try with two computers. I cannot get anything to send. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? I am just trying to learn.

Here is the server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace UDPServer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void ShowMessageMethod(string msg);

    UdpClient _server = null;
    IPEndPoint _client = null;
    Thread _listenThread = null;
    private bool _isServerStarted = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void serverMsgBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btStart.Text = "StartServer";
    } 

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isServerStarted)
        {
            Stop();
            btStart.Text = "StartServer";
        }
        else
        {
            Start();
            btStart.Text = "StopServer";
        }

    }
    private void Start()
    {
        //Create the server.
        IPEndPoint serverEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
        _server = new UdpClient(serverEnd);
        ShowMsg("Waiting for a client...");
        //Create the client end.
        _client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        //Start listening.
        Thread listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listening));
        listenThread.Start();
        //Change state to indicate the server starts.
        _isServerStarted = true;
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            //Stop listening.
            listenThread.Join();
            ShowMsg("Server stops.");
            _server.Close();
            //Changet state to indicate the server stops.
            _isServerStarted = false;
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        { }
    }

    private void Listening()
    {
        byte[] data;
        //Listening loop.
        while (true)
        {
            //receieve a message form a client.
            data = _server.Receive(ref _client);
            string receivedMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            //Show the message.
            this.Invoke(new ShowMessageMethod(ShowMsg), new object[] { "Client:" + receivedMsg });
            //Send a response message.
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server:" + receivedMsg);
            _server.Send(data, data.Length, _client);
            //Sleep for UI to work.
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    private void ShowMsg(string msg)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.Text += msg + "\r\n";
    }
}
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace UDPClient
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UdpClient _server = null;
    IPEndPoint _client = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
   private void serverMsgBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the server.
        _server = new UdpClient("127.0.0.1", 16000);
        //Create a client.
        _client = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _server.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception s)
        { 
        }
    }

    private void btSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Send the input message.
            string text = this.richTextBox1.Text;
            _server.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text), text.Length, _client);
            //Receive the response message.
            byte[] data = _server.Receive(ref _client);
            string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            //Show the response message.
            this.richTextBox1.Text = msg;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        { 

        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, when you want to check connectivity problems or debug what is being send, you can use a proxy like Fiddler or ZAP, so you are going to be able to intercept the traffic, analyze and manipulate it in case you need, and this is going to give you a lot of information.

As possible solution to your question take a look at [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services).